# Can't connect with PHP to my bplaced.net Mysql database (no error)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send some parameters from an HTML file with Ajax (jQuery) to my PHP file, which is also on the bplaced.net server. Near to everything is fine, my Ajax method sends the parameters to the PHP file, the PHP file receives them and is also connected with my Mysql database. The only problem when I try to insert in a table of the database nothing happens (no faults) table is still empty.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// Verbindung herstellen //
@$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

//Variablen
$a1 = $_POST["a1"];
$a2 = $_POST["a2"];
$a3 = $_POST["a3"];
$a4 = $_POST["a4"];
$a5 = $_POST["a5"];
$a6 = $_POST["a6"];
$a7 = $_POST["a7"];
$a8 = $_POST["a8"];
$a9 = $_POST["a9"];
$a10 = $_POST["a10"];
$a11 = $_POST["a11"];
$a12 = $_POST["a12"];
$a13 = $_POST["a13"];
$a14 = $_POST["a14"];
$a15 = $_POST["a15"];
$a16 = $_POST["a16"];
$a17 = $_POST["a17"];
$a18 = $_POST["a18"];
$a19 = $_POST["a19"];
$a20 = $_POST["a20"];
$a21 = $_POST["a21"];
$a22 = $_POST["a22"];
$a23 = $_POST["a23"];
$a24 = $_POST["a24"];
$a25 = $_POST["a25"];
$a26 = $_POST["a26"];
$a27 = $_POST["a27"];
$a28 = $_POST["a28"];
$a29 = $_POST["a29"];
$a30 = $_POST["a30"];
$a31 = $_POST["a31"];
$a32 = $_POST["a32"];
$a33 = $_POST["a33"];
$a34 = $_POST["a34"];
$a35 = $_POST["a35"];
$a36 = $_POST["a36"];

// Einfügen
$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('tim')";
$eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);

if($eintragen) {
  echo "Eintrag war erfolgreich";
} else {
  echo "Fehler beim Speichern";
}

mysql_close($verbindung);
?>
```

It echoes: "Fehler beim Speichern".

(PS: The other variables are not yet in use).

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","database")` that is a mysqli_ method of connecting with 4 arguments, not 3 as per mysql_.

Comment: *"(no error)"* - that's because of the @ being an error suppressor for `@$verbindung...`

Comment: Also `echo "Fehler beim Speichern"` will never give an error, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php will tell you about an error. I also hope in your real code you aren't using those `a#` variables in your query.

Comment: I removed the jquery / javascript tags since there was no code to support the question. If you feel it being relevant, you'll need to add that code and add the tags back in. The POST arrays are unknown if there are values for them or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this code to find out if the Connection is ok:

  try {
    $verbindung =         mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception vorhanden: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }

// Code fortsetzen
```

The Same with this piece of code to find out if your insert is working:

```
    Try { $eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);}
```